# Ng2samrt table: customized column

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I need to customize a column based on another column value. So I need to add a mat-icom to the ttc column regarding the warning column. However, the warn  value returns always True.

Is there any method how to use a column value in another one.
I'm not using the valuePrepareFunction because i do not need to change the TTC value, I just need to display or not the warning mat-icon depending on the column warning values.

```
      warning: {
        type: 'bool',
        translateTitle: 'Nothing',
        useTitle: true,
        hidden: true
      },
      ttc: {
        type: 'number',
        translateTitle: 'TTC',
        useTitle: true,
        unit: this.companyDevise,
        warn: [{ name: 'warning', values: [true] }]

      },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was pull the source and create a sanitize directive for the cell so that it will allow css / html input without throwing the html injection error.  It would be really nice if they would put it in.